# What's the standard way to use a Color object to change the color of HTML elements in Elm?

Tags: html, elm

I just started learning Elm and somehow can't find anything that applies a colour to to a div `elm-lang/html` nor `elm-lang/color`

```
import Html exposing (Html, div)
import Html.Attributes exposing (style)
import Html.Events exposing (onClick)
import Color

type alias Model = {
    color : Color.Color
}

view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
        div 
        [ 
            [ onClick ChangeColor ] , 
            [ style
                ( "background-color" model.color ??? ),
                ( "height", "200" ),
                ( "width", "500" ),
            ]
        ]
        []
```

Should I be using something other than `style` here, since it expects a List of (String, String) tuples? Or am I just not finding the right function for the type conversion?

(edited code to include the model)

Answer (score 4):

Color - or any other style attribute, like size, border, font etc etc - can be applied to an Elm Html element using either [style from Html.Attributes](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/html/1.1.0/Html-Attributes#style) (to apply individual style to an element) or by using [class from the same package](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/html/1.1.0/Html-Attributes#class) (to apply a css-class with multiple styles to an element).

Which is the standard depends on your specific use case. I would advise:

- If it is really static (color never changes), use CSS.
- If color is part of a set of style elements for on-off things like showing whether a button is enabled, or alternating colors in a list, use CSS.
- If color is really interactive, e.g. user can choose from color palette or slider, use style.

The docs on style include an example on background-color.

```
myStyle : Attribute msg
myStyle =
  style
    [ ("backgroundColor", "red")
    , ("height", "90px")
    , ("width", "100%")
    ]

greeting : Html msg
greeting =
  div [ myStyle ] [ text "Hello!" ]
```

Below (copyable to [elm-lang.org/try](http://elm-lang.org/try)) is an example on changing color.

```
import Html exposing (div, button, text)
import Html.App exposing (beginnerProgram)
import Html.Events exposing (onClick)
import Html.Attributes exposing (style)

type alias Model = String

init = "blue"

main =
  beginnerProgram { model = init, view = view, update = update }

view model =
  let
    myStyle =
     [ ( "width", "200px" )
     , ( "height", "200px" )
     , ( "backgroundColor", model )
     ]
  in
    div [ style myStyle ]
      [ button [ onClick ChangeColor ] [ text "Change color" ]
      ]


type Msg = ChangeColor

update msg model =
  case msg of
    ChangeColor ->
      case model of 
        "blue" -> "red"
        "red" -> "orange"
        "orange" -> "blue"
        _ -> "blue"
```

Comment: For the third choice, I suggest looking into CSS variables.  It allows you to mix dynamic styling from elm code and use of CSS.

Answer (score 1):

I found this [elm-color-extra][1] package with several Convert utilities. Does the trick, but I'm going to leave this question as unanswered for now in case there's a more elm-y way of doing it.

Here's my final program (after an `elm package install eskimoblood/elm-color-extra` in my project's top-level folder). It's a square that changes to a random color when you click on it:

```
module ColorSquare exposing (..)

import Html exposing (Html, div)
import Html.Attributes exposing (style)
import Html.Events exposing (onClick)
import Html.App

import Color
import Color.Convert

import Random


-- Model

type alias Model = {
    color : Color.Color,
    seed : Random.Seed
}

init : ( Model, Cmd Msg )
init = 
    ( 
        {color = Color.rgb 0 255 0, seed = Random.initialSeed 1234 },  
        Cmd.none
    )


-- Messages

type Msg = ChangeColor


-- View

view : Model -> Html Msg

view model =
        div 
        [ 
            ( onClick ChangeColor ) , 
            ( style [
                    ( 
                        "background-color", 
                        Color.Convert.colorToCssRgb model.color 
                    ),
                    ( "height", "200px" ),
                    ( "width", "500px" )
                ]
            )
        ]
        []

-- Update

randomColor : Random.Generator Color.Color
randomColor =
  Random.map3 Color.rgb (Random.int 0 255) (Random.int 0 255) (Random.int 0 255)

update : Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
update msg model = 
    case msg of
        ChangeColor ->
            let
                (color, seed) = Random.step randomColor model.seed
            in
                ({color = color, seed = seed} , Cmd.none )


-- Subscriptions

subscriptions : Model -> Sub Msg
subscriptions model =
    Sub.none


-- Main

main : Program Never
main =
    Html.App.program
        { init = init
        , view = view
        , update = update
        , subscriptions = subscriptions
        }
```